# Item Receipt From Return Authorization

Tags: netsuite

may I ask, I have custom field, I want the item receipts From Return Authorization only.
would u please help me to find the criteria how to do it?

Custom Field of Custom record

Answer (score 0):

To Enable us to provide a better answer better,
Please advise if you are trying to create a saved search? or a different function.

Saved Search Type : Transaction.

Criteria something similar to the below

Type > Item Receipt
Applied to Transaction fields... > Type : Return authorization.

you may need to specify if you need to look at the Mainline only ( Mainline = True) or at Line level, (Mainline = False)

if you only want Item receipts with this custom field populated then you could include in your criteria,  Custom Field = Not Empty

then its onto your results to be populated.

Comment: its custom field , so i want to use the source and filtering , not saved search